# PyCharm Complaining about Django `templatetag` Argument

Tags: python, django, pycharm, templatetag

Here is a snippet of code in a template that uses a custom `templatetag` I wrote that does work:

```
{% if theme == 'books_literature' %}
    {{ theme|prettify:'/' }}
{% else %}
    {{ theme|prettify:' ' }}
{% endif %}
```

PyCharm is complaining about the colon and the characters after the colon, even though they are valid...

Here is an image showing what it looks like:

[image]

The hover I get says I should add closing curly braces... Which makes sense, if it wasn't expecting an argument.

Comment: do you have the paid version? afaik only the paid one really supports html templating stuff ... the community version only really handles python well ...

Comment: I believe PyCharm doesn't offer community version, only paid. You can evaluate for 30 days and then you must either buy it or stop using... But, yes, I'm using the paid version...

Comment: what is the hover text you get? what OS and version also? (they definately do have a free community version... that is really only missing a couple of the features of the paid version, that said I also have a paid version)

Comment: Good question... I will add to OQ...

Comment: @nicorellius PyCharm community edition: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

Comment: Yes, indeed, they do have community version. I was mixing that up (my bad) with the fact that it doesn't fully support Django, eg, the community version, that is... Which is the main reason I'm using it. I'm running Linux.

Comment: I've reported it as PY-14890 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14890)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@thebjorn reported it as PY-14890 ( https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14890 )